# Web Scrape in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to web scrape https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Rankings and scrape the first table on the page, but it has not worked and I get an error 'NoneType' object is callable.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Rankings").read())

for row in soup('table', {'class': 'wikitable'})[0].tbody('tr'):
    tds = row('td')
    print tds[0].string, tds[1].string
```

I don't know much about HTML and I know very little about web scraping.

Comment: `row('td')`... `row` is not a method, and so it is not "callable". Same for `tbody('tr')` probably

Comment: Also - I would recommend that you use the request library, rather than the `urllib2` library - `requests` is a much nicer way of fetching web pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `findAll` (or `find_all`, if you want to be Pythonic) function to search for all tags under an element.

You may also want to do a check on the data to make sure you don't get an IndexError like so.

```
for row in soup('table', {'class': 'wikitable'})[0].findAll('tr'):
    tds = row.findAll('td')
    if len(tds) > 1:
        print tds[0].text, tds[1].text
```

And here's the output it gives

```
 Argentina 1532
 Belgium 1352
 Chile 1348
 Colombia 1337
 Germany 1309
 Spain 1277
 Brazil 1261
```

Comment: `.string` doesn't work. `.text` works.

Comment: Ran it myself in python2. `beautifulsoup4 (4.4.1)`

Comment: It may be a platform issue then. Gives me `None`.

Comment: Here's the docs, even. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string

Comment: Interesting because I also get None

Comment: http://imgur.com/ZKtzlfe And by the way, I did not downvote brother. I know it is a platform issue.

Comment: @AbdulFatir Hmm, I copied that from my OSX terminal, but running it in Jupyter I do get None

Comment: @cricket_007 I decided to change my answer to your solution because I was able to adapt it to other tables by using the requests package and changing some of the html classes. Thanks a ton for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Rankings")
sourceCode = BeautifulSoup(request.content)
tables = sourceCode.select('table.wikitable')
table = tables[0]

print table.get_text()
```

also if you want the results as a list:

```
list = [text for text in table.stripped_strings]
```

Comment: This gave me an error that said:  Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib. Do you need to install a parser library?

Comment: You can replace `html5lib` with `html_parser`, or just remove it.

Comment: it works without it, I just default to html5lib because some sites are finicky, sorry, should have specified that dependency

Comment: This was a great answer too, wish I could accept both.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You need to use `find_all` to look for tags. Also, in the Wiki article, team ranks are present in table rows 3-22, hence the if condition.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Rankings").read())

for i,row in enumerate(soup('table', {'class': 'wikitable'})[0].find_all('tr')):
    if i > 2 and i < 23:
      data = row.find_all('td')
      print i,data[0].text, data[1].text
```

Comment: this gave the correct output. If you don't mind explaining the enumerate part that would be fantastic

Comment: @AdamWarner [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: See `for row in rows` for example gives each row. `for i,row in enumerate(rows)` gives the current index in `i` and row in `row`. I hope I made it clear.

Comment: @AdamWarner Please mark it as the answer if it helped. :)

Comment: @AbdulFatir I tried to adapt this http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/matchday/league-table.html and could not figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AdamWarner Hi! What issue are you facing?

Comment: I hate it when people don't explain the down-vote.